# Yii CGridView : selectionChanged not defined

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I'm stuck with a problem on my CGridView. I want to make columns clickable, so that it redirects to a new page.

My problem is that I try to use `selectionChange`, and Yii throws an exception telling `Property "CDataColumn.selectionChanged" is not defined.`

Here is my code:

```
<?php   $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'columns'=>array(
            array('header'=>'First Name'
                , 'type'=>'raw'
                , 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'cursor: pointer;')
                , 'name'=>'first_name'
                , 'sortable'=>true
                , 'selectionChanged'=>'function(id){window.location=\'CHtml::link($data["first_name"],Yii::app()->createUrl("/athlete/view", array("id"=>$data["id"])))\'}'),
            array('header'=>'Last Name'
                , 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'cursor: pointer;')
                , 'type'=>'raw'
                , 'name'=>'last_name'
                , 'selectionChanged'=>'function(id){window.location=\'CHtml::link($data["first_name"],Yii::app()->createUrl("/athlete/view", array("id"=>$data["id"])))\'}'),
            array('header'=>'Date of Birth'
                , 'value'=>'Controller::date($data["dob"])'
                , 'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'90px', 'style'=>'cursor: pointer;')
                , 'name'=>'dob'
                , 'selectionChanged'=>'function(id){window.location=\'CHtml::link($data["first_name"],Yii::app()->createUrl("/athlete/view", array("id"=>$data["id"])))\'}'),
            array(
                'header'=>'Edit'
                ,'class'=>'CButtonColumn'
                ,'template'=>'{update}'
                , 'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/athlete/update", array("id"=>$data["id"]))'
            ),
        ),
        'pagerCssClass'=>'clist-pager',
        'pager'=>array('header'=>''),
    ));
?>
```

So, could you help me figure out why this exception is thrown, and fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define `selectionChanged` on the columns themselves, that property only exists on the grid view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'selectionChanged'=>'function(id) { /* ... */ }',
    // columns, etc
);
```

Comment: Ok, that was it, thanks. Quite noobish error, but I'm just starting with yii! :-)